# Order the results produced with Multiprocessing.Queue

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I wrote a generic multiprocessing wrapper function which

- takes a function and its inputs
- splits these inputs along their first dimension
- feeds the splitted inputs to multiple processes
- collects their results in a Queue and finally puts them back together (in the *correct order*)

The last bit is where I have problems. I use `multiprocessing.Queue` and the order in which results are put in this queue are not related to the order in which I call the processes, but the fastest process writes first.
Is there another way than also adding the index of the current process to the Queue and order the results afterwards?

I looked at `multiprocessing.Pool` but this method has a big overhead and works not if the  function is more complicated ("Can't pickle xxx object").
`multiprocessing.Array` is maybe an option but I don't know how to initialize it, so that I can but arbitrary elements (a tuple of numpy arrays) in each slot and use it basically as a list. I read that the elements of Array must be c_types...

The code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import time


def change_tuple_order(t):
    return tuple(map(lambda *tt: tuple(tt), *t))


def mp_wrapper(*args, fun, n_processes):
    
    if n_processes == 1:
        return fun(*args)
    
    n_samples = np.shape(args[0])[0]
    samples_per_process = n_samples // n_processes

    def __wrapper_fun(i_process, queue):
        queue.put(fun(*map(lambda a: a[samples_per_process*i_process:samples_per_process * (i_process+1)], 
                           args)))
        # Solution idea
        # queue.put((i_process,
        #            fun(*map(lambda a: a[samples_per_process*i_process:samples_per_process * (i_process+1)],
        #                args))))


    # Start the processes and save their results in a queue
    result_queue = mp.Queue(n_processes)
    process_list = []
    for i in range(n_processes):
        p = mp.Process(target=__wrapper_fun, args=[i, result_queue], name=str(i))
        p.start()
        process_list.append(p)

    # Make sure the queue is full before joining the processes with a small timeout, otherwise there occurred
    # errors, because a process which filled the queue but was still alive
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.001)
        if result_queue.full():
            break

    # Wait for the processes to finish
    for i in range(n_processes):
        process_list[i].join(timeout=0.001)

    # Combine and return the results
    results = [result_queue.get() for _ in range(n_processes)]

    # Solution idea
    # results = change_tuple_order(results)
    # idx = np.argsort(results[0])
    # results = [results[1][i] for i in idx]

    if isinstance(results[0], tuple):
        results = change_tuple_order(results)
        return tuple([np.concatenate(r, axis=0) for r in results])
    else:
        return np.concatenate(results, axis=0)


def f_test(x):
    time.sleep(np.random.random()*10)
    return x*x


def f_test2(x, y):
    return x**2, y**3, x+y


n_processes = 5
print(mp_wrapper(np.repeat(np.arange(n_processes), 10),
                 fun=f_test, n_processes=n_processes))
# [ 4  4  4  9  9  9  0  0  0  1  1  1 16 16 16]

print(mp_wrapper(np.repeat(np.arange(n_processes), 3), np.repeat(np.arange(n_processes), 3),
                 fun=f_test2, n_processes=n_processes))
# (array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 9,  9,  9, 16, 16, 16]), 
#  array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 8, 8, 8, 27, 27, 27, 64, 64, 64]), 
#  array([0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8]))
```

Most of the time the order of the results is fine, but it is obviously not deterministic which process is the fastest.

Is there way of using `Queue` or `Array` as a list, where i can write arbitrary elements at specific indices or do I have to keep track of the order of inputs and outputs myself?

Comment: that looks like you should be using `Pool().map`.  I'd suggest trying to figure out how to use it.  there are mostly the same pickling requirements as using a `Process` (except for the args when using `fork` start method, e.g. under Unix)

Comment: I know that It looks easier to use *Pool()* but in my case 1) the overhead when spawning a Pool is way larger than when starting the processes manually and 2) I am not able to integrate calls to c functions in the Pool() framework.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [a similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76696327/13040402), you can use [SeqQueue](https://github.com/highvight/seqqueue) to keep the order of indexed items.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34696749)